# How to create an instance of a class which relies on a HttpService in another service?

Tags: angular, http, angular6

I am trying to create a service-1 in angular 6. This service-1 will be used by service-2 to make http-requests.

**Service-1**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {
  constructor(
      private http: HttpClient
  ) {
     // do something with http
  }
}
```

**Service 2**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{ HttpService } from './user-account/http.service'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceTwo{
  http: HttpService;
  constructor() {
     this.http = new HttpService() ;
  }
}
```

This doesn't work because `this.httpService = new HttpService()` expects a parameter.

So I tried another approach:

**Service-1**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {
  http: HttpClient;
  constructor() {
     this.http = new HttpClient();
  }
}
```

**Service 2**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{ HttpService } from './user-account/http.service'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceTwo{
  http: HttpService;
  constructor() {
     this.http = new HttpService() ;
     // do something with http
  }
}
```

This doesn't work because the `HttpService` requires some argument. I don't know the details about this argument.

**Question: How to create an instance of a class which relies on a HttpService in another service?**

Comment: You should use DI instead of instantiating it directly

Comment: @user184994 Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dependency injection within your own services, just like the way you injected the HttpClient into service-1, you would inject service-1 into service-2's constructor as follows:

```
    export class ServiceTwo{
      constructor(private myService: ServiceOne) {

      }
    }
```

You can then use this injected service in your class by accessing "this.myService"

Comment: How would I call this from another service that imports this class?

Comment: Edited my answer, hopefully it's clear
You would use it just like the way you would call the HttpClient in your first service

Comment: This looks like it might work. I'll try it out tomorrow :).

Comment: I talked to someone else about this. And I was told that you should never use normal parameters in an angular constructor. Only parameters for Dependency Injection. So in this scenario I should not have created different instances of the HttpService. But instead passing a singleton service of HttpService using Dependency Injection.